# entity framework update relationship from database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, updatemodel

i have two table which have relation, tables like that:

First Table: ProductionDemand --- ID(PK),Name,RevisionID(FK, not null)

Second Table: Revision --- ID(PK), Name

I create model by using two tables and the other tables (about 20 tables)

But then RevisionID(FK, not null) to RevisionID(FK, null) and update model from database, i selected ProductionDemand table from refresh tab. I build my project and it failed. I get error from foreign key and entity classes not loaded.

I hope you know what I issue.

Note: The relation which is 1..* not changed in diagram after model updating. It must be 0..1 ....*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it manually to 0..1 by updating relation properties in model designer